# How to convert WaitAll() to async and await

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

Is it possible to rewrite the code below using the async await syntax?

```
private void PullTablePages()
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    var faultedList = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var featureItem in featuresWithDataName)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => PullTablePage();
        taskList.Add(task);

        if(taskList.Count == Constants.THREADS)
        {
            var index = Task.WaitAny(taskList.ToArray());
            taskList.Remove(taskList[index]);
        }
    }

    if (taskList.Any())
    {
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }

    //todo: do something with faulted list
}
```

When I rewrote it as below, the code doesn't block and the console application finishes before most of the threads complete.

It seems like the await syntax doesn't block as I expected.

```
private async void PullTablePagesAsync()
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>();
    var faultedList = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var featureItem in featuresWithDataName)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => PullTablePage();

        taskList.Add(task);

        if(taskList.Count == Constants.THREADS)
        {
            var anyFinished = await Task.WhenAny(taskList.ToArray());

            await anyFinished;

            for (var index = taskList.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            {
               if (taskList[index].IsCompleted)
               {
                  taskList.Remove(taskList[index]);
               }
            }        
        }
    }

    if (taskList.Any())
    {
       await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }

    //todo: what to do with faulted list?
}
```

Is it possible to do so?

WaitAll doesn't seem to wait for all tasks to complete. How do I get it to do so? The return type says that it returns a task, but can't seem to figure out the syntax.## Heading ##

New to multithreading, please excuse ignorance.

Comment: Change the return type of `PullTablePagesAsync` to `Task`  and await it in your main function/loop.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Your code isn't making much sense currently.

Comment: Run a list of tasks. If one completes, start another until all complete with respect to a limit of 4 at a time

Comment: Async/await are not for rewriting a blocking code. In fact they are specifically designed to be non blocking. The question makes no sense.

Comment: `async void` is only there for compatibility with events. If `PullTablePagesAsync` is not a event handler (which it does not look like one) you should not be using `async void`. See "[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)"

Comment: Is the answer that it's not possible to rewrite this using async await, because async and await are meant for nonblocking code? Not sure why you posted that as a comment @ivanstoev

Comment: @Hoppe, have you tried what Eser said?

Comment: I don't know, probably because I was concentrating on the meaningfulness rather than the possibility part. But once you asked, I did post an answer trying to use my best to explain (I'm not a natural English speaking and feel more comfortable positing a code fragments rather than explanations :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to rewrite the code below using the async await syntax?

Yes and no. Yes, because you already did it. No, because while being equivalent from the function **implementation** standpoint, it's not equivalent from the function **caller** perspective (as you already experienced with your console application). Contrary to many other C# keywords, `await` is not a syntax sugar. There is a reason why the compiler forces you to mark your function with `async` in order to enable `await` construct, and the reason is that now your function is no more blocking and that puts additional responsibility to the callers - either put themselves to be non blocking (`async`) or use a blocking calls to your function. Every `async` method in fact is and should return `Task` or `Task<TResult>` and then the compiler will warn the callers that ignore that fact. The only exception is `async void` which is supposed to be used **only** for event handlers, which by nature should not care what the object being notified is doing.

Shortly, `async/await` is not for rewriting synchronous (blocking code), but for easy turning it to asynchronous (non blocking). If your function is supposed to be synchronous, then just keep it the way it is (and your original implementation is perfectly doing that). But if you **need** asynchronous version, then you should change the signature to

```
private async Task PullTablePagesAsync()
```

with the `await` rewritten body (which you already did correctly). And for backward compatibility provide the old synchronous version using the new implementation like this

```
private void PullTablePages() { PullTablePagesAsync().Wait(); }
```

Comment: Seems like I was mistaken in believing that I could easily block/wait for the async await construct in my question

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the await syntax doesn't block as I expected.

You're expecting the wrong thing.

The `await` syntax should never block - it's just that the execution flow should not continue until the task is finished.

Usually you are using async/await in methods that return a task. In your case you're using it in a method with a return type void.
It takes times to get your head around async void methods, that's why their use is usually discouraged. Async void methods run synchronously (block) to the calling method until the first (not completed) task is awaited. What happens after depends on the execution context (usually you're running on the pool). What's important: The calling method (the one that calls `PullTablePAgesAsync`) does not know of continuations and can't know when all code in `PullTablePagesAsync` is done.

Maybe take a look on the async/await best practices on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)